# How to auto add string "http://' when user input in the textbox by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to automatically prepend `http://` to the value of a textbox.

For example, `cateno.no` should become `http://cateno.no`, but `http://google.com` should stay the same.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input id="urlBanner" type ="text" style ="width:450px;" maxlenght="100" />
```

Comment: When do you want the check to occur?

Answer (score 7):

You could bind to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event for the `input` and evaluate the value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#urlBanner").change(function() {
        if (!/^http:\/\//.test(this.value)) {
            this.value = "http://" + this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/gnHLz/

Or, if you don't like regular expressions you could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#urlBanner").change(function() {
        if (this.value.indexOf("http://") !== 0) {
            this.value = "http://" + this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fYRUW/

Answer (score 5):

I would make a slight alteration to Andrew Whitaker's regex example to account for https urls, otherwise https://test.com will be prepended with http:// and look like http://https://test.com

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#urlBanner").change(function() {
        if (!/^https*:\/\//.test(this.value)) {
            this.value = "http://" + this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle some event, probably `change`, and prepend the string if the current value doesn't match a regular expression:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#urlBanner').bind('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if(!/^http:\/\//.test($this.val()) {
            $this.val('http://' + $this.val);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem, params) {
// if no url, don't do anything
if (val.length == 0) { return true; }
// if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) {
    val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
    $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
}
else if(/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) { // set both the value
    $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
}
// now check if valid url
return /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(val);}, 'Please enter valid URL');
```